# Cypress doesn't see custom cy. commands

Tags: typescript, cypress

Cypress can't import custom command

commands.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('generateToken', ({secret}) => {
    const totp = require('totp-generator');
    const token = totp(secret); 
    });
```

support/index.js

```
import './commands'
```

test.spec.ts

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

context('Actions', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {})
  })
    it('Main test', () => {
        cy.generateToken('XXXX');
    })
```

All the time generateToken() is underlined in test.spec.ts and error appears:

```
Property 'generateToken' does not exist on type 'cy'.
```

index.js and commands.js were not moved from original directories. cypress.json file is empty.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since your spec is a typescript file, did you add a new types definition for the `support/index.js`?

Their documentation seems to outline it pretty well [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support.html#Types-for-custom-commands). Only thing that is different with their example though is that you're not returning anything from `generateToken` so I don't think you can place it into the global `Chainable` interface.

You could try adding this in a `support/index.d.ts` file and see if it yells at you

```
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    generateToken({secret}: {secret: string}): void
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks like it works! No access to work repo to check, will do it tomorrow. I had to change the code a little bit: 

declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      generateToken(secret): void
    }
  }

Could you please explain why it worked?

Answer (score 11):

Since the proposed answer of nshirley did not work for me, I found [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-documentation/issues/2565#issuecomment-651251129) comment.
It is very similar but adds `declare global` at the top, to declare these custom commands on a global scope.

Here is a working example:

**cypress/support/commands.ts**:

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject> {
      /**
       * Provides a working example
       */
      generateToken(secret: any): Cypress.Chainable<Element>;
    }
  }
}

const generateToken = (secret: any) => {
  // Your Code
};

Cypress.Commands.add("generateToken", generateToken);
```

And in your test you can just use it:

```
cy.generateToken("Example");
```

As you can see, you can even provide some documentation for your methods, but that is completely optional.

Comment: This is the right answer here. It needs to be in the global namespace.

Answer (score 11):

Fully working in 2021.

for `support/index.ts` file

```
import './commands'
```

for `support/commands.ts` file

```
Cypress.Commands.add('generateToken', generateToken);
function generateToken({secret}): void {
    const totp = require('totp-generator');
    const token = totp(secret); 
}

// this is another example.
Cypress.Commands.add('login', login);
function login(username: string, password: string): void {
    // steps for login 
}

declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject> {
       generateToken({secret}): void;

       /**
        * This will log user in
        * @param email string
        * @param password string
        */
       login(email: string, password: string): void;
    }
}
```

for `test.spec.ts` file

```
cy.login("somebody@domain.com", "something");
cy.generateToken("Example");
```

None of the other answers worked for me. I wanted to have type support in the VS Code as well as I didn't want to face `cypress Property does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'` runtime error.

I have added another example of login with JSDoc support.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I get TypeScript to see my custom commands:

**commands.ts**

```js
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    generateToken(secret: any): Cypres.Chainable<void>;
  }
}

function generateToken(secret: any): void {
  // Generate token
}

Cypress.Commands.add('generateToken', generateToken);
```

**test.spec.ts**

```js
cy.generateToken(secret);
```

Comment: I don't have commands.ts file. I have only commands.js. Where did you create it?

Comment: I just called it commands.ts instead of commands.js. Your index file can still just use `import './commands';`

Answer (score 2):

add the path in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "include": [
    "integration/*.ts",
    "support/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `Cypress.generateToken('XXXX');` Does that work?

Also, try to remove unnecessary parentheses while adding the command. Try this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('generateToken', secret => {
    const totp = require('totp-generator');
    const token = totp(secret); 
});
```

Comment: No, the same problem.
```
any
Property 'generateToken' does not exist on type 'Cypress'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: I've updated the answer, maybe you have had a parentheses issue there? If that doesn't work, I can't help :/

Comment: Pfff...no idea man. Check out our repo here, we've been using Cypress to do some testing and have couple of custom commands in there. Maybe you'll find some difference between yours and ours which will be the key..https://github.com/boxwise/dropapp/tree/master/cypress/support

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in support/command.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('generateToken', (secret) => {

       const totp = require('totp-generator');
       const token = totp(secret);
  };
  cy.request(options)

});
```

Then in your js code

```
    /// <reference types="Cypress" />

context('Actions', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {})
  })
    it('Main test', () => {
        const token ='XXXX'
        cy.generateToken(token);
    })
```

**Edit 1**

Can you add this and can add more iterative waits as per the test you have

```
describe('check the tokens', function() 
{
// on 30 seconds 
it('first token ',()=> {
    cy.wait(30000).then(()=>{
        const token = getToken();   // You're waiting here for 30 sec before you get token
        console.log('first token: ' + token);
    })
})
// on 60 seconds 
it('second token', ()=>{
    cy.wait(60000).then(()=>{
        const token = getToken();
        console.log('second token: '+ token);
    });
})
})

function getToken () {
    const totp = require('totp-generator');
    const token = totp('ABCD');
    return token;
  }
```

Comment: No, the same problem.

Comment: @A.Makarevich - In that case I would create a function in the test.spec and call it. see my edit

Comment: The problem is, that this function is called at the beginning of the test, but test itself lasts for more than 30 seconds, and token expires. I need to regenerate it each time I suppose to use it.

Comment: @A.Makarevich - yeah thats a pain. I have edited more on edit 1, may be try that one and can add iterative waits on it when needed

Comment: No, hardcore waits like this is not an option for me.

Comment: @A.Makarevich- ok but you can play around in such a way say your all test takes average time of 50 sec, now with this hardcore wait you're actually not letting totp to generate a new token with in 50 sec. I dont see an issue here

Answer (score 0):

Try below and see if it works.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('generateToken', { prevSubject: false }, ({secret}) => {

   // Your code.

});
```

Comment: Didn't help. Even if I uncomment some example function in commands.js, it still can't be used in test.

Answer (score 0):

An approach for devs who do not want to declare the typings of any command in `cypress.d.ts`, at least at the time of experimenting.

With this declaration file, any command can be added and called without Typescript complaining.

```
// cypress.d.ts 

import { mount } from "cypress/react"

declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
            mount: typeof mount
            [k: string]: (...args: any[]) => Chainable<Subject>
        }
    }
}
```